# AWS Lambda's failure to recognize JS modules in Node.js

Tags: node.js, typescript, aws-lambda, deployment, es6-modules

I had a working Node 16 Lambda backend. After converting it to typescript, when I deploy, I get this error in CloudWatch: `"SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"`. This does not occur when running locally.

Changing `module` in tsconfig to `commonjs` has been suggested as a solution. However, doing so yields `ReferenceError: exports is not defined in ES module scope` when running locally.

What might be the solution?

**full error**

```
        "Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError: SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module",
        "    at _loadUserApp (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:997:17)",
        "    at async Object.UserFunction.js.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1035:21)",
        "    at async start (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1200:23)",
        "    at async file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1206:1"
```

**package.json**

```
  ...
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "prebuild": "rm -rf dist",
    "build": "esbuild handler.ts --bundle --minify --sourcemap --platform=node --target=esnext --format=esm --outfile=dist/handler.js",
    "postbuild": "cd dist && zip -r handler.zip handler.js*"
  },
  "type": "module"
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "ESNext"],
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "module": "esnext",
      "target": "esnext",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "resolveJsonModule": true,
      "isolatedModules": false,
      "noEmit": true,
      "outDir": "dist",
      "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
      "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
      "strict": true,
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "useUnknownInCatchVariables": false,
      "inlineSourceMap": true,
      "rootDir": ".",
      "baseUrl": ".",
      "paths": {
          "@/*": ["./*"],
      },
    },
    "include": [
      "./*",
      "*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules",
      "public"
    ],
    "ts-node": {
        "esm": true,
        "require": ["tsconfig-paths/register"]
    },
    "lib": ["esnext"]
}
```

**handler.ts**

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = "prod";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import app from "./app.js";
...
export const lambdaHandler = async (event: any, context: any) => {
   ...
}
export default { lambdaHandler };
```

**deployment**

`aws lambda update-function-code --function-name jigglypuff-kicks-ass --zip-file "fileb://dist/handler.zip"`